# how to disable unlock screen sound on galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens

Lately my phone makes an annoying sound when unlocking the screen. I don't have "Screen unlock sound" checked in the setting. I googled and found few people complained about this issue but no solution has been found yet. I tried checking and unchecking the setting and restarting the phone many times but still no joy. A hard reset might help but i don't want to do that if not absolutely essential.

This is not me but just found on youtube and this guy seems to have exactly same issue.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3m2Dyv-jaY

Anyone here had same issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the comments with 9 Likes in the video says: `Settings > More settings > Under file/data﻿ transfer, turn off NFC`

Comment: thks +1 from me for idea as for me the same settings were in `Settings > More ( Wireless & networks ) > NFC` for ressurection custom ROM i am using