# How can I know which app is giving me notification sounds?

Tags: notifications, audio

I've removed the permission for almost every app to show me notifications on the status bar but now that led me to a situation in that a lot of times during the day there will be a notification sound (which in my case is an annoyingly loud "boom", which I use because that's the only way I can hear the Redy Gym Log notification that my rest time is up with the loud sound in the gym) but I don't know from which app it came from. Is there any way for me to turn off sound notification? I can't find that on App Opps. Maybe an app that would show a behind the scenes system log would be great, if that kind of thing exists. I'm on a Galaxy Note 3.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this helped me:

[how to disable unlock screen sound on galaxy S3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51042/how-to-disable-unlock-screen-sound-on-galaxy-s3)

I had turned on NFC to transfer data from an old phone. NFC makes your phone chirp every time you unlock / wake it to remind you it's on. Turn it off under `Settings (Wireless & Networks) -> More -> NFC`

Comment: Sorry, the question is about *identifying* the source of the notification sound. While your answer *might* be one of the causes of the notification sound, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This helped me. When I turned off the NFC the sound gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For system logs you have the "logcat" command.

you culd try killing apps one by one untill you find the naughty one. But unchecking notifications should work, so are you sure you disabled almost all? It's probably an app that is still notification enabled

Comment: how do I use this "logcat" command?